# How do I log in as myself in Facebook(PHP SDK) from my local machine? and perform tasks that are like me doing it manually?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

So far all i got is this:

1. installed wampserver on my local machine downloaded the PHP SDK and
2. extracted src/Facebook into my localhost/app_name/ and copied the
3. autoload.php into my localhost/app_name

I don't want to set up a real server that does a real app, just want to run it locally on my machine to graph this relationship to one of the page(s) that i admin.
and i got this to execute with no errors (index.php)

```
<?php
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR','/wamp/www/78611337341/Facebook/');
require_once("autoload.php");
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookCanvasLoginHelper;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('78611337341', 'actual_secret_key_goes_here');


?>
```

Now I need to login as me (in code) and perform these operations: Go to one of the pages i created that has just under 200 likes, get all people who like the page, and see if they're friends of each other (provided I can manually see their friends when I manually log in and perform the task myself).

Basically I intend to build something like this graph (this graph is only fictional friendship right now) that maps out friendships based on who liked it first and then others who are friends to the upper nodes like the page after and so on for each layer [image: fictional graph but people are real]

any pointers would be appreciated... I tried looking up facebook access-tokens and got confused.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not possible to accomplish with Graph API.  You cannot get the friend list of any user unless that user specifically grants your app the "user_friends" permission.  Which means, in your example above, you would not be able to see the Zaw Moe and Howard Travis friendship unless BOTH Zaw and Howard granted your app access to their friend lists.

Comment: that's too bad then :(

Answer (score 0):

The global theme of what you are tying to do requires the [`user_friends` permission scope](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-user_friends), and - like user3268305 says in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248368/how-do-i-log-in-as-myself-in-facebookphp-sdk-from-my-local-machine-and-perfor#comment48600631_30248368) - even with that permission scope, you will only be able to get those friends that have installed the same app, *and* granted the `user_friends` permission scope.

However, your original question was:

> How do I log in as myself in Facebook(PHP SDK) from my local machine?

Given your mention of the "wampserver", I'm assuming you want to run a webapp on your local machine and implement a website login on that machine. The way you do that is by simply visiting your app's app settings at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/YOUR_APP_ID/settings/ and add a "Website" platform.

In the site URL, you enter `http://localhost` or similar (screen shot below). This is - of course - assuming that you don't already have a live and public version of your app running somewhere else.

[image: app settings]

Answer (score 0):

I never could get the http://localhost to work for me on the FB App website settings.

I change the /ect/host so 127.0.0.1 has an alias like cooldude.com and the FB App has the same domain.

/ect/host

127.0.0.1    cooldude.com

facebook:

domains include cooldude.com and website url to it as well.